# Type safe String interpolation in Scala

Tags: scala, type-safety, scala-macros, string-interpolation, scala-macro-paradise

Inspired by [this](http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-safe-printf-via-type-providers/), I was wondering if we can have type-safe string interpolations in Scala (maybe using macros)?

For example, I want to have something like this

```
def a[A] = ???
val greetFormat = f"Hi! My name is ${a[String]}. I am ${a[Int]} years old" 
greetFormat.format("Rick", 27)  // compiles
//greetFormat.format("Rick", false)  // does not compile
//greetFormat.format(27, "Rick") // does not compile
//greetFormat.format("Rick", 27, false) // does not compile
//greetFormat.format("Rick") // does not compile or is curried?
```

Answer (score 3):

The `f` string interpolator is already implemented with a macro.

This can be demonstrated inside of the REPL:

```
scala> val b = "not a number"
b: String = not a number

scala> f"$b%02d"
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: Int
              f"$b%02d"
                 ^
```

Comment: I see. But, it forces me to supply formatters for it to trigger the type check fail e.g. if I just do `f"$b"` and `b` is an `Int` it will still work. I want something like `f"${a[String]}"`

Comment: @wrick That really has nothing to do with type-safe string interpolation - you want to make sure variables conform to types that aren't even required by the string interpolation. In any case, what you want can be easily done with `f"${a: String}"`

Comment: `f"$b"` is just shorthand for `f"$b%s"`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in a function.

```
def greet(name: String, age: Int) = s"Hi! My name is $name.  I am $age years old"
```

Comment: Probably a better design in most cases but does not answer OPs question about how to do it in a *generic* fashion

Answer (score 1):

You can supply implicits to the f-interpolator:

```
scala> case class A(i: Int)
defined class A

scala> implicit def atoi(a: A): Int = a.i
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
atoi: (a: A)Int

scala> f"${A(42)}%02d"
res5: String = 42
```

See also [Travis Brown's examples](https://github.com/travisbrown/type-provider-examples) and solution for [using regex group names in extractions](https://github.com/travisbrown/expressier).  It took me about a minute to steal that great idea.

```
"a123bc" match {
  case res @ xr"(?<c>a)(?<n>\d+)(?<s>bc)" => assert {
    res.c == 'a' && res.n == 123 && res.s == "bc"
  }
}
```

For the record, on the composition side, I would like:

```
val a = A(Rick, 42)
val greeter = f"Hi! My name is $_. I am ${_}%d years old" 
greeter(a, a)
```

But it was deemed too much for the poor underscore.  You'll have to write the function as in the other answer.

Your form, in which your macro sees `"${a[Int]}"` and writes a function with an `Int` param, doesn't look hard to implement.

Other features of the f-interpolator include other static error checking:

```
scala> f"$b%.02d"
<console>:19: error: precision not allowed
              f"$b%.02d"
                   ^
```

and support for `Formattable`:

```
scala> val ff = new Formattable { def formatTo(fmtr: Formatter, flags: Int, width: Int, precision: Int) = fmtr.format("%s","hello, world") }
ff: java.util.Formattable = $anon$1@d2e6b0b

scala> f"$ff"
res6: String = hello, world
```

A quick macro might emit `(i: Int) => f"${ new Formattable {...} }"`.